# Copy data from one database to another database which is in remote location

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a database locally and a similar type of database in a remote location, Now for every minute my local database will be inserted with some 50 to 100 records. Simultaneously I have to insert these records into the remote database which is residing in a database server that has a public IP. There wont be any LAN or WAN, this has to be done using internet but that server is accessible using publid IP, Is there any possibility that I can do this using Triggers or some thing from SQL server itself? Or should I have to write some webservices using .NET(Basically .net application is logging the data to this database. Please help me out in this.
Thanks,
Rama

Comment: you should use periodic updation rather than simultaneously update

Answer (score 0):

[Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176#HowWorks) can be deployed over Internet, recommended though [using a VPN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152569.aspx) (or [DirectAccess](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/dd420463.aspx)). An alternative is to use [Service Broker instead of Replication](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/using-service-broker-instead-of-replication/).

Things that do **not** work are web service calls, triggers, .Net custom applications and similar. When it comes to preserve transactional integrity (guarantee commit or rollback at *both* servers), detect data changes, application availability when the remote DB is down or accessible (think patching), maintainability, serviceability, not to mention handling [HR/DR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx) solution for either site, all these solutions fail in real life.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a windows service which will update the data there in remote server. If you don't want to use replication of your database.

The basic idea would be like this.

Windows service will watch for the database changes and if anything are in. It will upload those all changes with SQLBulkyCopy classes.

To know more about the SQLBulkCopy class visit following link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Here is a working example of SQLBulkCopy class-
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server